# How to correctly display a chart on JS client, created on server using Python Plotly?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, plotly

I want to display a chart created using Python Plotly in my front-end (written in JavaScript). The chart is created in my back-end (running on Python Flask) and has the following structure:

```
#document                                // chartDoc
<div>                                    // outerDiv
   <div></div>                           // innerDiv
   <script> innerScriptText </script>    // innerScript
</div>
```

I send it as a string inside a JSON file: `{"chart": my_chart_str}`.

**The problem:** I receive the chart in my JS, I create a new `<script>` element, I fill it with the code to display the chart (otherwise the browser doesn't execute the script, only prints it as plaintext) and I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined
    at Element.<anonymous> (plotly-latest.min.js:20)
    at plotly-latest.min.js:20
    at ut (plotly-latest.min.js:20)
    at Array.Y.each (plotly-latest.min.js:20)
    at Array.Y.style (plotly-latest.min.js:20)
    at lt (plotly-latest.min.js:61)
    at Object.r.plot (plotly-latest.min.js:61)
    at Object.r.newPlot (plotly-latest.min.js:61)
    at <anonymous>:1:210
    at code.js:38
```

which comes from the plotly.js library and is caused by a `div` component that evaluates `this.style` as `undefined`.

But if I take the received chart code and manually paste it inside an `.html` file, the chart is displayed fine.

**Basically what I'm trying to do is automating the procedure described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56824092/5827223).**

This is the minimal code to reproduce my error:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./code.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="graph-container">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**code.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
  displayChart();
}

function displayChart() {
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/chart", {
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    method: "GET"
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      let chartString = response.chart;
      let chartDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(chartString, "text/xml"); // #document

      // get elements from received graph
      let outerDiv = chartDoc.firstElementChild;
      let innerDiv = outerDiv.firstElementChild.cloneNode();
      let innerScriptText = outerDiv.lastElementChild.innerHTML;

      // recreate same structure with new component and old content
      let newOuterDiv = document.createElement("div");

      let newInnerScript = document.createElement("script");
      newInnerScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

      let newInnerScriptText = document.createTextNode(innerScriptText);

      newInnerScript.appendChild(newInnerScriptText);

      newOuterDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
      newOuterDiv.appendChild(newInnerScript);

      // insert graph in the page
      document.getElementById("graph-container").appendChild(newOuterDiv);
    });
}
```

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)

class Chart(Resource):
    def get(self):
        my_chart_str = str(get_chart())
        return {"chart": my_chart_str}

def get_chart():
    # taken from dash "getting started" guide
    import plotly.graph_objs as go
    from plotly.offline import plot

    x  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    y1 = [9, 6, 2, 1, 5, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3]
    y2 = [19, 36, 12, 1, 35, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3]
    trace1 = go.Bar(x=x,
                    y=y1,
                    name='Boats')
    trace2 = go.Bar(x=x,
                    y=y2,
                    name='Cars')

    data = [trace1, trace2]
    layout = go.Layout(title='Title',
                    xaxis=dict(title='X axis',
                                tickfont=dict(size=14,
                                                color='rgb(107, 107, 107)'),
                                tickangle=-45),
                    yaxis=dict(title='Y axis',
                                titlefont=dict(size=16,
                                                color='rgb(107, 107, 107)'),
                                tickfont=dict(size=14,
                                                color='rgb(107, 107, 107)')),)

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    return plot(fig,
        include_plotlyjs=False,
        output_type='div')

api.add_resource(Chart, "/chart")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

Start the server (I'm on Windows) with `python server.py`, open `index.html` in your browser (double click on it, not via localhost), open the developer console and you should see the error.

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Just a question. Why you do not use dash directly for this ? Asking to understand the actual use case

Comment: I don't have control over the technologies used in this project. Furthermore, it has to be managed by front end developers in JS and pyhton data scientists in the backend.

Comment: I see. Imo this is not correct as approach then. Just use a FE library to draw charts like charts.js or high-charts or w/e and your BE should only send the data to fill the graphs.

Comment: I get your point, but graphs are a fixed size result of potentially millions of data-points, in which case sending the graph is more convenient than sending data-points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround.

Instead of sending the chart as a JSON string, I do the following:

1. From `index.html` a JQuery function call the Server.
2. The Server creates the chart (in the form of a `div`) and saves it in a file named `chart.html`.
3. The Server returns to JQuery the `chart.html` file.
4. JQuery receives the file and insert it into `index.html` ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003363/5827223) helped me figurig out how to embed an html file inside another).

My working code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>CHART WILL BE SHOWN BELOW</p>
      <div id="chart-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
(function () {
    window.onload = function () {
        getChart();
    }

    function getChart() {
        $("#chart-container").load("get_chart"); // chart will be inserted in "chart-container"
    }
})();
```

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder='', template_folder='')
CORS(app)

def create_chart():
    # sample graph
    import plotly.express as px

    fig = px.imshow([[1, 20, 30],
                    [20, 1, 60],
                    [30, 60, 1]])
    fig.write_html("./chart.html", include_plotlyjs=False, full_html=False)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("/index.html") # return "index.html" without chart

@app.route("/get_chart")
def get_chart():
    create_chart() # create "chart.html" file
    return render_template("/chart.html") # return chart to jquery

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

To run it, first start the server (windows: `python server.py`) then open the browser and navigate to `127.0.0.1:5000`.